# Does cellulase catalyze the hydrolysis (or break down) of soluble starch?

Tags: titration, chemical-biology, hydrolysis, enzymes

I’m attempting to perform an Iodometric redox titration to evaluate the vitamin c concentration in a particular solution. These solution have dissolved within them up to 2% cellulase enzyme.

In an iodometric redox titration, a 0.5% starch indicator solution would be used to inform when endpoint occurs via it’s reaction with excess, un-neutralized iodine indicator solution.

Will the cellulase in solution interfere with this titration process by perhaps hydrolyzing the starch indicator solution?

If so, should I try and denature the cellulase in solution before performing the redox titration?